# result = result.decode('utf-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 321: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I have this code:

```
        try:
            execute = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            print('execute', execute)
            result = execute.stdout.read() + execute.stderr.read()
            print('normal result', result)
            result = result.decode('utf-8')
            print('decoded result:  ', result)
            reliable_send(result)
        except:
            reliable_send('Something went wrong ;- (')
```

Some commands like whoami or arp-a are working fine and i receive the result to my server, but when i try to get dir or ipconfig this line **result = result.decode('utf-8')** throws an exception, what is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

The error:

result = result.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 321: invalid start byte

Comment: What are the exceptions? Is it an encoding error or is the command returning an error?

Comment: The code runs to the ( result = result.decode('utf-8') ) line and doesnt even print ( print('decoded result:  ', result) ) but throws except and run ( reliable_send('Something went wrong ;- (') ), so I guess something is wrong with the decoding but I cant figure out what

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what is that something that is going wrong? A sad face is unfortunately not a very good error message, could you change the code so that you can print the exception and post it in the question?

Comment: result = result.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 322: invalid start byte
I guess thats it

Comment: Great. That should be added to the question. Now you should look for that specific exception because it's not at all uncommon to find it and there are multiple questions that have already been answered regarding that and it's possible that you posted a duplicate question.

Comment: Why do you think the output from the process is a utf-8 encoded byte sequence? Because that's the only time it makes sense to use `.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
result.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

It kinda works, sometimes it returns something weird but overall it worked fine for me. If anyone knows a better solution I would love to know it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example subprocess.Popen has been opened in a byte stream mode so you need to know the encoding to interpets these bytes as text.

If `encoding` or `errors` are specified, or `text=True` passed to `subprocess.Popen`, the file objects stdin, stdout and stderr are opened in text mode with the specified encoding and errors, as described above in [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

You could experiment with [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) as well to get proper results.

From time to time I run into a problem of detecting encoding and have found a console tool [enca](https://github.com/nijel/enca) useful for it.

Comment: print() does not raise an error, decode() does.